# Live preview + share button missing when switching to PRO licence

Tags: craft-pro

At first, I thought the latest update was the problem, but apparently, by buying a license and switching to PRO, the buttons disappeared. Is there a magic trick to get them running again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've seen something similar happen. I don't know the cause of it, but the solution in the 2 cases I know of each has the same fix. What happened was that for some reason, the "preview targets" got wiped out. In my case, this was during an update to the database. In another person's case that I know of, I think an upgrade was involved.

From within the control panel, go to "Settings -> Sections" then click the name of the section that is missing the preview buttons. Look at the bottom of the page and see what it says in the "Preview Targets" area. It should look something like this screenshot. If it doesn't add a new row and fill it in like the image shows.

[image: Preview Target definition in Craft CMS control panel]

Comment: Thanks John,    
Adding a row at the Preview Targets was the solution!